# Adjusting Visual Studio 2017 debugger settings in CMake

Tags: debugging, cmake, visual-studio-2017

I know about new target properties in modern CMake for Visual Studio debugger: `VS_DEBUGGER_COMMAND`, `VS_DEBUGGER_COMMAND_ARGUMENTS` and so on.
How can I set these properties for Debug configuration only? Should I use `set_target_properties`?

I'd like to pass debug version name of my dll to settings. I have release and debug dlls: mylibrary.dll, mylibrary**d**.dll.

So, `VS_DEBUGGER_COMMAND` contains the full path to dll loader.
In my case `VS_DEBUGGER_COMMAND_ARGUMENTS` must contain **non-hardcoded** variant of the full path to debug dll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set_target_properties` or `set_property` can be used.  To set it for a specific configuration you would use generator expressions.

`set_property(TARGET foo PROPERTY
  VS_DEBUGGER_COMMAND $<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:FOO_EXTRA_THINGS>
)`

I'm not sure what the second thing you seem to be asking.  All paths are hard-coded. If you are asking how to use a Visual Studio variable then just use that variable in FOO_EXTRA_THINGS (remember the quoting).

`set_property(TARGET foo PROPERTY
  VS_DEBUGGER_COMMAND $<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:\$(ProjectDir)>
)`